# Display error in boxMessage Android

Tags: android, syntax-error

I try to display error in my project of Java but i found ProgressDialog but i don't want the progress.
What i can do ?

```
            if(login.getText().toString().length()>=5){
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", login.getText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.getText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            }else{
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Registration.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Login must contains more than 5 characters");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: Consider an `AlertDialog`

Comment: Use `AlertDialog` or `Toast`

Answer (score 0):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder ErrorMSg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 TextView Error = new TextView(this);
 Error.setText("Login must contains more than 5 characters");
 Error.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
 ErrorMSg.setView(Error);
```